# UILabel display regular updates whilst loop is being executed

Tags: loops, uilabel

I have a very long loop calculation. In order to give the user an idea of progress I would prefer to update some of the output data displayed in UILabels so the user can view the interim output.

```
// Run Activity for Year
    for (int day = 1; day < 366; day++) {
        for (int hour = 1; hour < 25; hour++) {
            for (int minute = 1; minute < 61; minute++) {
                display = (day*10000)+(hour*100)+minute;
                self.displayTest.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%d", display];
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously the self.display.text won't be updated until the `-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` has completed.

How do I get it to refresh the data, say whenever the hour loop is completed? Do you put in a phantom button and refresh it. That strikes me as a little crude. I don't want to have to resort to using an Activity Indicator or Progress View. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not perform the logic on a separate `NSThread` and run UI updates on main thread occasionally? for example, each time all "hour" iterations finished (reached 24, after each "day"), perform your UI logic on the main thread.

---

Example:

```
- (void)updateUI:(NSNumber*)display {
    self.displayTest.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@", display];
}

- (void)yearStuff {
    for (int day = 1; day < 366; day++) {
        int display;
        for (int hour = 1; hour < 25; hour++) {
            for (int minute = 1; minute < 61; minute++) {
                display = (day*10000)+(hour*100)+minute;
            }
        }
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:display] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yearStuff) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the logic and am sure it is right. I suspect something is missing as it only updates the literal when the loop is finished. Is there something I need to add or initialise?

Comment: It's actually [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:display] waitUntilDone:YES];